# Двоеточие перед выключными уравнениями

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие, авторская-пунктуация

Столкнулся с тем, что в одном издательстве два тома моего учебника корректоры правили совершенно по-разному. Я избегаю ставить двоеточия перед выключными уравнениями, делаю это крайне редко. Корректор первого тома с такой манерой вполне согласился. Корректор второго тома понаставил двоеточия почти всюду, в том числе после слова "Пусть" (с которого начиналось предложение) и после слов "предположим, что". Он ставил двоеточие после слов "уравнения" перед формулами, но после слов "уравнения Максвелла" почему-то не ставил. **А как правильно расставлять знаки препинания вокруг выключных уравнений?** По моему мнению, выключка сама по себе выделяет систему уравнений, так что лишние двоеточия только мешают.

Приведу два примера из корректуры:

Стр. 28

```
Раскрывая производные слева с помощью легко проверяемых формул:
 уравнение 1,
 уравнение 2,
перепишем последнее уравнение в виде
 уравнение 3.
```

Стр. 29

```
Поскольку для функции (3) выполнены равенства:
 уравнение 1,
 уравнение 2,
 уравнение 3,
условия (16.9) при и = 0 приводят к уравнениям:
 уравнение 1,
 уравнение 2,
 уравнение 3,
где . . .
```

В следующем примере двоеточия в моём варианте не было, корректор поставил двоеточие, другой корректор при второй корректуре -- снял.

Стр. 72.

```
Плотность электрического заряда и плотность электрического тока
соответственно равны:
 уравнение1,
 уравнение2.
```

Насколько помню из школьной программы, если слово уравнения в этих примерах рассматривать как обобщающее, то после перечисления самих уравнений надобно ставить тире. Однако тире никогда не ставят.

Comment: У Вас опечатки, проверьте текст, хотя он и правился уже. А главное: вопрос, тот что выделен жирным, достоин ссылки на правило, — он не конкретен, да и примеры схематичны.

Comment: @shampar: В том-то и дело, что я не знаю других правил, кроме параграфов 159 и 160 у Розенталя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В "Справочной книге корректора и редактора" А.Э. Мильчина (альфа и омега любого корректора) сказано об этом коротко: "Двоеточие ставят перед формулами только тогда, когда этого требует построение текста, предшествующего формуле". Следовательно, выключка формул не имеет значения и знаки должны ставится так же, как в случае сплошного текста. Я думаю, что в приведённых примерах не должно быть ни одного двоеточия. Хуже всего в последнем случае (стр. 72), в котором ошибочное двоеточие приводит к искажению смысла. Приведу простой пример, когда двоеточие ставится после фразы "соответственно равны":

Треугольники ABC и DEF называются подобными, если их углы соответственно равны:
|_ A = |_ D,
|_ B = |_ E,
|_ C = |_ F.

В этом примере двоеточие стоит перед уточнением/разъяснением сказанного. Но это имеет совсем не тот смысл, что на стр. 72.

Если бы на стр. 29 в тексте были бы, например, формулировки "выполнены **следующие** равенства" и "приводят к **таким** уравнениям", тогда ставилось бы двоеточие на общих основаниях.

Вам нужно переубедить корректоров. Я бы посоветовал найти в гугло-книгах хорошие примеры физико-математических текстов с бесспорно авторитетной корректурой (издательства "Мир", "Наука" и т.п.) с полностью аналогичными формулировками. Таких примеров тысячи и они достаточно легко ищутся. Если Вы лично общаетесь с корректорами, можно показать им бумажные издания.

Comment: Я принял Ваш ответ. Он в целом соответствует моему пониманию проблемы, но также показывает, насколько хрупка грань между тем, ставить двоеточие или не ставить. В общем, нужно думать над смыслом фраз, но два человека могут понимать смысл по-разному. В школьных сочинениях я менял фразу, когда сомневался в знаках препинания, но в книге хочется наиболее точно донести смысл. В Вашем примере перед двоеточием напрашивается "а именно", поэтому и нужно двоеточие. Уже хоть какая-то подсказка. Спасибо.

Comment: Можно ли трпетовать двеоточе как замену слов то есть в следующем примере:

В частности, интегрируя уравнение непрерывности (16а) по ма-
лой окрестности границы, нетрудно доказать, что на границе (в систе-
ме отсчёта, где она неподвижна) должна быть непрерывна нормальная
к границе компонента вектора (:)
             [[  ]] = 0.                         (22)

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov Да, конечно. Я думаю, здесь двоеточие необходимо.

Comment: Уважаемый @grizzly, я продолжил тему вопросом https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463178/Двоеточие-перед-выключными-уравнениями-2.