# Двоеточие перед выключными уравнениями (2)

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

Продолжая мой вопрос [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463115/Двоеточие-перед-выключными-уравнениями](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463115/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8), прошу ответить, как расставляются знаки препинания перед уравнениями после слов *получаем*, *находим*, *имеем* и т.п. Приведу несколько примеров.

Пример 1

```
Воспользовавшись решением задач 18.11-18.14, получаем(:)
 Eq1,  Eq2, 
 Eq3,  Eq4,
 Eq5,  Eq6.
```

Пример 2

```
Пренебрегая в этом уравнении инерцией электронов, 
то есть слагаемым mndu/dt и вязким трением V • пе, имеем(:)
         Eq1,
    где
         Eq2.
```

Пример 3

```
Выражая отсюда J и сравнивая результат с формулой Балеску J = а Е* — р' - VTC ,
находим(:)
     Eq1,  Eq2.
```

С одной стороны, у Розенталя есть такое правило:

§ 162. Двоеточие ставится между двумя предложениями, не соединенными посредством союзов, если в
первом предложении такими глаголами, как видеть, смотреть, слышать, знать, чувствовать и т. п.,
делается предупреждение, что далее последует изложение какого-нибудь факта или какое-нибудь
описание.

Если математическое предложение рассматривать как предложение, то надо вроде бы следовать этому правилу. С другой стороны, в ответе на цитированный вопрос читаем:

В "Справочной книге корректора и редактора" А.Э. Мильчина (альфа и омега любого корректора) сказано об этом коротко: "Двоеточие ставят перед формулами только тогда, когда этого требует построение текста, предшествующего формуле".

Это достаточно расплывчатая формулировка. Читая корректуру своей книги, для себя я выработал правило: ставлю двоеточие там, где вместо него хотелось бы написать *то есть*, *а именно*, *поэтому*, *что*, *так что*.
У меня ещё есть время скорректировать это правило, если меня здесь поправят. Заранее благодарен за любые пояснения.

Answer (score 2):

Между правилами Розенталя и Мильчина нет противоречия. Более того, Мильчин как раз и говорит, что в математическом тексте мы должны руководствоваться теми же правилами постановки двоеточия, что и в обычном.

Вы правы: все Ваши примеры попадают под указанное Вами правило Розенталя о постановке двоеточния после некоторых глаголов перед последующим изложением фактов.

Думаю, Ваше понимание правила постановки двоеточия требует небольшой коррекции (хотя интуитивно Вы всё делаете правильно, похоже). У Розенталя есть несколько правил постановки двоеточия, которые Вы пытаетесь объединить в одно правило. Лучше рассматривать их отдельно:

1. Двоеточие после обобщающего слова перед перечислением. Например, в конструкциях типа "выполнены [**следующие**] равенства:", "находим [**такие**] решения:" и т.п. Слова в скобках могут подразумеваться: если этих слов в тексте нет, но их можно вставить, тогда двоеточие нужно, иначе — не нужно (именно поэтому не нужны двоеточия в примерах прошлой темы на стр. 28 и 29; попытка вставить в те предложения подобные слова приведёт к стилистически неправильным конструкциям).
2. При наличии после обобщающего слова слов типа **как-то, а именно, например, то есть** двоеточие ставится после этих слов перед перечислением.
3. Двоеточие между двумя частями предложения, когда вторая часть раскрывает содержание первой (между этими частями можно вставить **а именно**, либо уже стоит что-то вроде **следующим способом, таким способом** и т.п.).
4. Двоеточие между двумя частями предложения после глаголов типа *видеть, смотреть, слышать, знать, понимать и т.п.*, если они предупреждают что далее последует изложение какого-либо факта или какое-нибудь описание (в этих случаях между частями предложения можно вставить союз **что**). (Это как раз относится ко всем примерам данной темы.)

Я привёл наиболее распространённые правила, немного сгруппировав их. Более точно и подробно можно посмотреть [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150) и [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=76).

**Дополнение.**
Розенталь говорит, что не всегда после общего слова ставится двоеточие (просьба обратить внимание на данные в скобках примеры Розенталя со словом **следующие**):

> Не ставится двоеточие также перед однородными членами в том случае, когда они представлены географическими названиями, которым предшествует общее для них определяемое слово, после которого при чтении пауза отсутствует: *Славятся своими здравницами города-курорты Кисловодск, Железноводск, Ессентуки, Пятигорск **(ср.: …следующие города-курорты: …)***.
>
> То же при перечислении названий литературных произведений, которым
> предшествует родовое наименование, не играющее роли обобщающего слова:
> *Романы Гончарова «Обломов», «Обрыв», «Обыкновенная история» образуют
> своего рода трилогию **(ср.: Следующие романы Гончарова: …)***.

Comment: Розенталя читал и перечитывал, но всё равно не понимаю, нужно ли в следующем примере считать слово *уравнения* обобщающим и, соответственно, ставить двоеточие. 

Здесь же мы примем соглашение, что параметры па, иа и Та в формуле (6) определяются из [следующих] уравнений(:)
Aa=..., 
Ba=...,
Ca=....
Кстати, заметьте, что после слова *параметры* перед их перечисленение нет двоеточия, а после них нет тире. Не видел нигде и никогда такого.

Comment: Переформулирую вопрос в примере из предыдущего коммента: можно ли слово "уравнения" считать обобщающим, если далее следуют математические уравнения?

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov Да, слово "уравнения" можно считать общим, но не всегда после такого общего слова должно стоять двоеточие. И математика здесь ничем не отличается от обычного текста. Я дополнил ответ соответствующим пунктом из правил Розенталя. Одни и те же фразы в разных контекстах будут с двоеточием или без. Отличать приходится по наличию паузы или по опыту / интуиции. К сожалению, не могу объяснить лучше (поскольку для этого нужно самому понимать глубже :) Может, кто-то из более опытных участников поможет, раз сама проблема находится за пределами математики.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov Уверен, что ситуация в предложении "параметры па, иа и Та в формуле (6)" аналогична той, в которых по Розенталю не ставится двоеточие.

Comment: Да, я тоже хотел сослаться не те исключения по Розенталю. Постановляем приравнять математические формулы к географическим названиям. Или названиям детективных романов?

Comment: Вот это правило, как мне кажется, подходит под часто встречающиеся ситуации со словами параметры, уравнения, асимптотики, формулы:

4. Если однородным членам предложения, выраженным собственными именами лиц, предшествует общее для них приложение, не выступающее в роли обобщающего слова (при чтении в этом случае отсутствует характерная для произнесения обобщающего слова пауза), то двоеточие перед ними не ставится: Писатели-классики Гоголь, Тургенев, Чехов рисовали картины из жизни крестьян.

К тому же я нашел подтверждение в Механике Ландау-Лифщица, переиздавнной несчётное число раз.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov Ну да, это правило из того же пункта, возможно, оно подходит лучше. Я попытался поискать специальную литературу про специфику пунктуации в научных текстах, но ничего про эту особенность для двоеточия не нашёл. Я несколько лет (давно уже) работал в типографии "Докладов АН" с лучшими редакторами страны, какого-только опыта не набрался, но вот чего-то подобного совершенно не припомню, даже странно как-то.

Comment: Хорошо бы такое пособие написать. Его остро не хватает. Я готовлю книгу в издательстве, которое опубликовало много хороших книг по моей специальности, но и там разные корректоры по-разному трактуют правила. В двух томах два разных корректора совершенно по-разному расставили именно двоеточия.

Answer (score 0):

Придумал пример, когда после одной и той же фразы (по моему скромному мнению) в одном случае нужно ставить двоеточие, а в другом не нужно. Всё зависит от последующей формулы.

Пример 1.

```
Поперечный ток выражаем из уравнения равновесия изотропной плазмы:
    \[
    \vec{J}_{\bot}
    =
    \frac{c}{B^2}[\vec{B}\times\nabla p]
    .
    \]
```

Тут двоеточие нужно, так как следует выражение для плотности тока, найденной из уравнения равновесия.

Пример 2.

```
Поперечный ток выражаем из уравнения равновесия изотропной плазмы
\[
\nabla p
=
\frac{1}{с}[\vec{J}\times\vec{B}]
.
\]
```

Тут двоеточие не нужно, так как за фразой следует поименованное выше уравнение. Уравнение записано в разметке LaTeX.

Сказанное выше ставит под сомнение сказанное в "Справочной книге корректора и редактора" А.Э. Мильчина, где написано коротко: **"Двоеточие ставят перед формулами только тогда, когда этого требует построение текста, предшествующего формуле"**. Если же я прав, то конечно не следует на 100 процентов доверять корректору, который не обладает необходимым образованием.

Comment: Согласен с Вашим примером и с выводами.

Answer (score 0):

Примеры из Механики Ландау-Лифшица (Наука, 1988).

Стр.74

```
Выразив отсюда $\sin(\chi/2)$ через $\varepsilon$ и подставив в (19.2), получаем:
    \[
    \dif\sigma = \ldots 
    .
    \]
```

Стр. 74

```
Угол отклонения $\chi=2(\alpha -\beta )$. Поэтому имеем:
    \[
    \frac{\sin(\alpha -\chi/2)}{\sin\alpha }
    =
    \ldots 
    .
    \]
```

Стр. 75

```
Наконец, дифференцируя это равенство, получим эффективное сечение
    \[
    \dif\sigma = \ldots 
    .
    \]
```

Стр. 75

```
Обозначив посредством p' импульс частицы после рассеяния, 
имеем очевидное равенство
    \[
    \sin\theta = p'/p
    .
    \]
```

Сравнивая эти примеры, я бы сделал вывод, что двоеточие заменяет отсутствующее название последующего математического уравнения или выражения.

Естественно, это только один случай расстановки знаков препинания в предложениях с математическими формулами.